# Jest expect mock to be called with an object not containing a specific field

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I want to verify that a mocked API is called with an object which does **not contain** a specific field.

```
expect(api.method).toBeCalledWith(expectedObject);
```

Since the actual parameters of the `api.method` call can be a subset of the `expectedObject` this test also passes if the `actualObject` contains further fields (among which the specific field might be).

How can I rewrite the test in a way, that the tests fails if the `actualObject` is not equal to the `expectedObject`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
// get the first call to your method
const method = api.method.mock.calls[0]; 

//check if you have expectedObject as a subset of the arguments
expect(method[0]).toMatchObject(expectedObject); 

//key is the field that shouldn't be part of the arguments
expect(method[0].has(key)).toEqual(false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Karim! That got me on the right track!

Answer (score 3):

```
// since several tests use this mock I have to ensure to have the latest call
const lastMockApiCall = api.method.mock.calls[api.method.mock.calls.length - 1]; 
const apiCallParams = lastMockApiCall[0];
expect(apiCallParams).not.toHaveProperty('specificFieldIdontWant');
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following

```
expect(body[0].email).toEqual(undefined);
```

Which is passing when there is no email in the first object of the returned API array.